# Why is the Yod smaller in Pinchas' name in Bamidbar 25:11?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, aleph-bet-letters, pinchas-the-man

Pinchas is mentioned several times in the Tanach but in the pasuk Bamidbar 25:11 this is the only time the 'yod' in his name is diminished in size. I don't know if every manuscript has this anomaly. It was explained to me that his small act of obedience with his hand was instrumental in the Covenant of Peace. I wanted to know if this is a correct interpretation of this pasuk or is there another explanation. I could not find anything else in my research.

Comment: To which manuscript are you referring? Two very early surviving codices from the 10th Century do not show a diminutive _yod_.  That is, both the [Codex Leningrad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsMMu.png) and the [Orientales 4445](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebjex.jpg) codices reflect normal scripting of the _yod_. Both codices, however, have a margin note to indicate that the word **פִּינְחָס** occurs only once in Scripture as the first word of the verse.

Comment: Minchas Shai says something on the topic, but I can't seem to figure out what he's saying, if anyone wants to take a stab at it. In general, though, Minchas Shai just makes a note on these sorts of things, without explaining the reasoning behind them.

Comment: Can you provide a pic or a link to it? I don't know how many readers are familiar with this.

Comment: @Joseph I don't know the manuscript where this was found. It was part of a discussion where it was mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

https://hatam-soferet.dreamwidth.org/443763.html

A good source. Two possible explanations:
-They weren't sure if the Yud was supposed to be there, so drew it smaller in case.
-Mystically,  using violence to solve your problems diminishes the presence of God within you, so the Yud (indicating God) is diminished in Pinchas.